# Javascript expandable menu - sample code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I'd like to know if anyone knows how I can implement something like the following?

Here's a sample below:

[image]

And once you click on the plus, the menu expands:

[image]

I've googled and have found quite a few menus. But I'm looking for something that has this +/- functionality.

Comment: Typically the + and - are images that you control yourself which are toggled when you click on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me doing this, I'd do a jquery ui accordion with a single div.  By default they use an arrow for the toggle, but it'd be trivial to change that out.  [Here's a tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#custom-icons) on changing icons.  It's infinitely adaptable using the API.

The biggest benefit is that if you already use jQuery UI, there's nothing else to load.  You can't beat ThemeRoller for styling, either.

Comment: Thanks @bpeterson76. I found how I can change the icons as well... pretty simple!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing complicated here :) A simple slideToggle in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) binded to a click on that plus image and you have your effect :)

Comment if you need more code to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, you can use a  [TreeView extension](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview)

Once you have the HTML set up, one simple javascript call will get it working.

$("#yourDiv").treeview();

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview